# Grammar or specification of Bison/Lemon files

Tags: grammar, bison, context-free-grammar, lemon, bisonc++

I need to write parser for Bison and Lemon grammar files. I'm looking for specification or grammar of these files format. Any links will be helpful.

Comment: I write such [parser](https://github.com/melihovv/grammar_review_tool/blob/702c1e10b65a1c5f37b199ab6ca51f55761995b3/src/parser/Lemon.g4) with anlr4. Maybe it will be usefull for someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to get a grammar of Bison as it is bootstrapped: just get [its parser from the repository](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bison.git/tree/src/parse-gram.y).